# Why does a zero byte app.config file cause a very strange error?

Tags: c#, app-config, console-application

[image: Error]

**The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.**

This is caused when you have an app.config which is zero bytes. The error appears to come from Windows - even WinDBG won't launch it.

I know it's completely invalid to have a zero byte app.config, but what causes this error, where does it come from and why does it happen?

Comment: .config files are usually xml files, so even if it's empty, it needs some xml structure/signature in the beginning. So the config file, as it's empty, can't be parsed as an XML, so i think it's an internal security mechanism to stop the app from running, as no tool or program that would alter the .config file would cause it to have that state, so it MUST be altered by hand, which would cause the program to run incorrectly. at least, it's one more step of a security measure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_FILE_INVALID
//
// MessageText:
//
// The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.
//
#define ERROR_FILE_INVALID               1006L
```

Copied from the WinError.h Windows SDK header file.  The symbolic error code here is obviously much more pertinent than the boilerplate error message text.  This is not quite unusual.  I can see it being used inside the SSCLI20 source code (the open source version of the CLR) in code that checks if the executable has  the proper PE32 file header and the .NET header present in a managed assembly.  Clearly that doesn't apply here.

Nevertheless, the CLR is interested in the app.exe.config file at a very early moment in the bootstrapping stage.  Elements like `<supportedRuntime>` must be parsed before the CLR can get started.  Clearly this code is not happy with an empty .config file.  The CLR code is awesome like that, it never does the 'let's stumble on anyway' cop-out.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll remember to look at WinError.h for these kinds of things in the future. I'm guessing there would be no way to handle this kind of situation in managed code?

Comment: Of course there is!  Fix the file.  Well, no, not managed code.